# combine two data sets in tableau so that I can show a forecast for the next 3 months

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am trying to take a take a bar chart and add in another bar chart for the next three months that will show how many people we expect to drop from our CRM. The original shows two other metrics. The image below is what I would like the outcome to be. As you can see it is just a screen shot of different bar charts. Would appreciate any advice on how to complete this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to do it should be to make two worksheets (let's call then `Sheet A` and `Sheet B`).
In `Sheet A` you place the first bar char and in `Sheet B` the second bar char (the forecasting).

After that you can create a dashboard and place both of them [horizontally alligned](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6VUi/how-to-align-sheet-content-on-dashboard).

You probably have to syncronize the axis of the two worksheet, following (for example) [this](https://interworks.com/blog/dsirey/2019/01/16/synchronize-axes-across-multiple-sheets-in-five-simple-steps/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have to data files or Excel tabs with similar or identical columns. Call one actual data and the other forecasted data. Use Tableau's UNION feature to concatenate the data together. Optionally, write a boolean calculated field that uses the Sheet or Tableau Name field to distinguish actual values from forecasted values -- or just rename the Sheet Name field something like "Record Type".

That will make it easier to combine actual values and predicted values in the same worksheet, while still distinguishing between them. Usually better than trying to manually align two views on a dashboard